# respond to selector method for unsupported implementations

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6

In my app I need to display **under line text** in a label so I used following code to display underlined text

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributeString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:normalString];
    [attributeString addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName
                            value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]
                            range:(NSRange){0,[attributeString length]}];

wesiteAddressLabel.attributedText = attributeString;
```

This method and some other implementations which works fine in iOS 6.1

But when I executed in iOS 5.1 and below, app gets crashed due to the reason,

```
[attributeString addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName
                            value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]
                            range:(NSRange){0,[attributeString length]}];
```

**not supported in previous versions**

So I want to use `respondsToSelector:` method to check if instance responds and implement another method for unsupported selector.

How I use this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As from the documentation:

> attributedText The styled text displayed by the label.
>
> @property(nonatomic,copy) NSAttributedString *attributedText
>   Discussion This property is nil by default. Assigning a new value to
>   this property also replaces the value of the text property with the
>   same string data, albeit without any formatting information. In
>   addition, assigning a new a value updates the values in the font,
>   textColor, and other style-related properties so that they reflect the
>   style information starting at location 0 in the attributed string.
>
> Availability Available in iOS 6.0 and later. Declared In UILabel.h

You should check if the a specific `UIView` element is able to respond to the `attributedText`. In this case:

```
[wesiteAddressLabel respondsToSelector:@selector(attributedText)];
```

Should be enough

Answer (score 1):

For previoes versions you have to draw an `UIImageView` Just below the Text by getting the with and Height of text in each line.

Or you can create a category of label by using `DrawRect` method.

```
    - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
 {
  CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 0.0f/255.0f, 0.0f/255.0f, 255.0f/255.0f, 1.0f); // Your underline color
  CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 1.0f);

  UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f];
  CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(MAXFLOAT, MAXFLOAT);
  CGSize labelSize;
  labelSize = [self.text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];  

  CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, 0, self.bounds.size.height - 1);
  CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, labelSize.width + 10, self.bounds.size.height - 1);

  CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

  [super drawRect:rect];  
}
```